# Confused about Sequelize associations

Tags: node.js, database-design, sequelize.js

I just found Sequelize as a good ORM framework to use in my node + MySQL webapp. But when I was designing my database tables, I got so confused about Sequelize associations.

Just think about user and system notification in a webapp as a very simple case:

- The site has many users
- The site would send notifications to some or every users, and the same notification just save as one record
- Users could know any notification he/she received is read or not(by a read date)

Then I design 3 tables as expect:

1. `User`: `id`, `name`
2. `Notification`: `id`, `title`, `content`, `sendAt`
3. `Notify`: `id`, `UserId`(as receiver), `NotificationId`, `readAt`

I can simply define `User` and `Notification` models by Sequelize. But I just don't know how to use associations to make `Notify` relate to the 2 tables, by foreign key `UserId` and `NotificationId`.

I have tried to use `hasOne` associations like this:

```
Notify.hasOne(User);
Notify.hasOne(Notification);
```

Then there comes a `NotifyId` column in both `User` and `Notification` tables. And this is not as my expect. Maybe I thought a wrong way to use associations, so I wanna know how to use it correctly?

Additionally, if I want to get results as the JSON:

```
[
    {id: 123, user: [Object some user], notification: [Object some notification], readAt: null},
    {id: 124, user: [Object another user], notification: [Object some notification], readAt: "Mon Oct 29 2012 20:44:54 GMT+0800"}
]
```

how can I use `find` method query just once like in a SQL I used before:

```
SELECT
    Notify.id as 'Notify.id',
    User.name as 'User.name',
    Notification.title as 'Notification.title',
    Notification.sendAt as 'Notification.sendAt',
    Notify.readAt as 'Notify.readAt'
FROM User, Notification, Notify
WHERE
    Notify.UserId = User.id AND
    Notify.NotificationId = Notification.id;
```

Comment: "Then there comes a NotifyId column in both User and Notification tables. And this is not as my expect." How would you expect, excuse me?

Comment: I expect NotifyId should not be exist in both User and Notification tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And I found right way. I realized that my Notify table is a entiry table because containing a `readAt` column. So the association should be defined as:

```
Notification.hasMany(db.Notify);
User.hasMany(db.Notify);
```

then everything became OK.

The second problem in `find` has been resolved too. Just use like this:

```
Notify.findAll({
    include: ['User', 'Notification']
}).success(function (notify) {
    console.log(notify.user);
    console.log(notify.notification);
});
```